# Using shift register in place of large mux

Tags: digital-logic, fpga

Large multiplexers can take a lot of logic and limit fmax of a design e.g a mux that selects one of 8 512-bit words. I think an alternative to this is to use a shift register where the maximum latency to select a word will be equal to number of words being selected.

Assuming that latency is acceptable, a shift register can be used in place of a giant mux.

Now my question is, is such a thing ever done in practice? Will it really give logic saving since a shift register like this won't contain just registers but some logic will still be required to make it work. Is there a name for replacing a mux with shift register in this way?

Comment: Yes it's done. Sometimes it'll give a saving (especially in Xilinx FPGAs < 15 years old where the LUTs all have a hack for the job). Only way to know if the savings are worthwhile for your application is to try it. Xilinx call it SRL16 (but that's a proprietary term) https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp465.pdf

Comment: You can pipeline the mux fairly easily if the frequency is a problem, but you need high throughput.  Another option on an FPGA if high throughput isn't necessary would be to use LUTRAMs and write all your inputs into a memory and then read the appropriate one.  I think you'd get better latency that way than using it as a shift register.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for a dual-port circular buffer RAM. Then you leverage the optimized select logic in the RAM block instead of instancing an explicit mux.